# magento attribute value is not saving in database

Tags: javascript, php, database, magento

we are using magento marketplace multivendor site.

we gave an option for vendor to update the product details in frontend.

we are using this code for updating the price. its working fine.

**Phtml**

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>


<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**JS**

```
function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setPrice($upd_price);
        $product->save();

        echo $price = $product->getPrice();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

In the same way we need to update the custom attribute "local" .

we are using following code to update local. **but its not saving in database**.

attribute code ="local"
attribute value = "Local"

**Phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('local');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>

<?php endif; ?>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" />


<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="local_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>


<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>

</span>
```

**JS**

```
function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**controller.php**

```
 public function updateFieldLocalAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setLocal($upd_local);

        $product->save();

        echo $local = $product->getLocal();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
  $product->setLocal($upd_local);
```

with

```
  Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
  $product->setStoreId(STORE_ID)->setLocal($upd_local)->save();
```